# EF Parent-Child relationship where ChildID in Parent could be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity "Parent" that includes id of an entity "Child" that includes id to entity "Parent" as parent.
For entity "Parent" more than one entity "Child" may be possible.
"ChildID" of Entity "Parent" may is null in db. I.e. no "Child" current selected.
If ChildID of entity "Parent" is null, EF should not does mapping for this field.

simplified:

```
class Parent
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int? ChildID
    public Child Child {get; set;}
}

class Child
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ParentID{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public Parent Parent {get;set;}
}
```

When i launch EF did a mapping is abracadabra.

I redesigned the db to added a new table contains ParentID and ChildID.

How to solve this competently? Would be without addition table.

Comment: is your code using database first approach or code first approach.?

Comment: I am use System.Data.SQLite, vs2017community. Therefore, I can't use VS's features to automatically building. So i did manually build DB's tables. After that I typed code.

Comment: if you build the DBs first, then you can use database first approcah and EF will automatically create these classes for you

Comment: As far as I understand your comment you use DB first approach. Therefore you have not to create the entity models by your own. You can just use the EF features via PMC (Package Manager Console) or the visual designer (if available - not sure for VS Community edition). Here is some help for [DB first approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx) and here some help for [code first approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx).

Comment: OK. I had to install VS2015C in order to test your above advice. EF did create public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }. But I need public Child Child {get; set;}. I.e. it have to point to only one item or null.